# To Find the maximum consecutive sum of integers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have this implementation, the result of this program is 100 but the correct answer is 103.
is anyone knows what is wrong in this implementation or if there is a better way for Finding the maximum consecutive sum of integers in an array?

**Thanks in advance.**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int a[] = { -3, 100, -4, -2, 9, -63, -200, 55 };
int max_sum, temp_sum, i, n = 12, t;
temp_sum = max_sum = a[0];
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i] > 0)
        temp_sum += a[i];
    else {
        t = 0;
        while (a[i] < 0 && i < n) {
            t += a[i];
            i++;
        }
        if (temp_sum + t > 0) {
            temp_sum = temp_sum + t + a[i];
            if (temp_sum > max_sum)
                max_sum = temp_sum;
        } else if (i < n)
            temp_sum = a[i];
    }
}
if (temp_sum > max_sum)
    max_sum = temp_sum;
printf("Maximum Numbers is %d \n", max_sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: there's smt weird here, I copied your code into CodeBlocks and the result is 332 ??

Comment: Is this homework? You should consider using recursivity.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum consecutive sum"? How can you get 103?

Comment: @ThiemNguyen: [same thing on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zNAuz).

Comment: @Saphrosit 100 + -4 + -2 + 9. That much, at least, OP got right.

Comment: Without understanding the algorithm, the first thing that jumps out is that n is 12 and a[] is only defined up to a[7].  So looping for i < n will access memory garbage.

Comment: I get 100 --> http://codepad.org/S9DqtZv6

Comment: @ Thiem Nguyen I try it know, but my result was 100!

Comment: YAY! **Undefined Behaviour** is out having fun again :)

Comment: @Saphrosit it's a interview question, maybe it's better to use "the largest sum of consecutive numbers"

Comment: Just a note - this algorithm appears to not work if all values are negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the correct indexes:

see here for demo : http://codepad.org/wbXZY5zP

```
int max_sum, temp_sum, i, n = 8, t;
temp_sum = max_sum = a[0];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    (...)
}
```

Comment: so `n=8` and loop from 0 to 7 (so `i=0` as start)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm). In C++ it will be something like this (untested):

```
int maxSubarray(std::vector<int> a) {
    int maxAll = 0, maxHere = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        maxHere = std::max(a[i], maxHere + a[i]);
        maxAll = std::max(maxAll, maxHere);
    }
    return maxAll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation's indices were incorrect, as noted by other users. I felt it was necessary to add an answer, however, to point out that your implementation fails if all values are negative (and the closest-to-positive number is not in the first position).

A quick fix for this issue would be to add a check when assigning temp sum in the case where `a[i] < 0 && temp_sum + t < 0` - at the last else block.

```
} else if (i < n) {
    temp_sum = a[i];
    if (temp_sum > max_sum)
       max_sum = temp_sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is looking for the largest consecutive sum not starting at index 0, the easiest way would be to have two loops

```
int max_sum, temp_sum, i, n = 8, t;
max_sum = a[0];
for (t = 0; t < n; t++) {
    temp_sum = 0;
    for (i = t; i<n; i++) {
        temp_sum += a[i];
        if (temp_sum > max_sum)
            max_sum = temp_sum;
    }
}
```